# Custom UILabel is not displaying text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I have created UILabel subclass which is IB_DESIGNABLE and has few IBInspectable properties.

I can see attributed text in all iPhone simulators and in interface builder.

I can see the text in iPhone 5c running iOS 9.3.

**BUT no text is displayed for iPhone 6 series of devices which are also running iOS 9.3.**

To debug I set background colour to the custom label, I can see the label frame filled with given colour but not text is displayed.

I even try commenting **applyStlyeOnText:** method, but even after that no text is displayed on iPhone 6.

I am using custom fonts, font file is added to project correctly.

**Update: Just updated to Xcode 8.0, on iOS 10 simulators, MyLabel is displaying nothing.**

Below is the implementation:

Header File:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface MyLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat letterSpacing;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat lineSpacing;

@end
```

Implementation File:

```
#import "MyLabel.h"

@implementation MyLabel

-(void)setLetterSpacing:(CGFloat)letterSpacing
{
    if (_letterSpacing != letterSpacing) {

        _letterSpacing = letterSpacing;

        [self applyStlyeOnText:self.text];
    }
}

-(void)setLineSpacing:(CGFloat)lineSpacing
{
    if (_lineSpacing != lineSpacing) {
        _lineSpacing = lineSpacing;
        [self applyStlyeOnText:self.text];
    }
}

-(void)applyStlyeOnText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (text.length){

        NSMutableDictionary * attributes = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        if (self.lineSpacing > 0)
        {
            NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
            paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = self.lineSpacing;
            paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
            paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment;
            [attributes setObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
        }

        if (self.letterSpacing > 0) {

            [attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.letterSpacing] forKey:NSKernAttributeName];
        }

        [attributes setObject:self.font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
        [attributes setObject:self.textColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
        [attributes setObject:[UIColor greenColor] forKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];

        self.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];

        NSLog(@"MyLabel - Stlye applied on text : %@", text);
        NSLog(@"Thread : %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        //no text recived to apply style on.
        self.attributedText = nil;
        NSLog(@"MyLabel - Stlye applied on text : empty string received");
    }
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    [super setText:text];

    NSLog(@"MyLabel - set text called with text : %@", text);
    NSLog(@"Thread : %@", [NSThread currentThread]);


    if (self.lineSpacing > 0 || self.letterSpacing > 0)
    {
        [self applyStlyeOnText:text];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug, I created a new single view app and added MyLabel.h and MyLabel.m files to project.

**I Used Xcode 8 and iPhone 5S simulator.**

But the result were same no text was being displayed by MyLabel.

Frustrated me, removed all the code from **MyLabel.h** and **MyLabel.m** except properties in **MyLabel.h**, overall class looked like below:

Header File:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface MyLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat letterSpacing;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat lineSpacing;

@end
```

Implementation File:

```
#import "MyLabel.h"

@implementation MyLabel

@end
```

Even with above code, no text was displayed by `MyLabel`.

Now I decided to rename the properties like below:

```
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat ltrSpacing;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat lnSpacing;
```

Surprisingly `MyLabel` started displaying the text, weird.

Then I re-introduced my logic and everything is working fine.

I think the property names I chose were conflicting with some of `UILabel`'s private properties but I am not sure about the exact reason.

Comment: Seeing the same behavior. Having a property named "lineSpacing" prevented text from drawing in my subclass.